# laravel multiple read data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Iam learning laravel.I don't understand how to read multiple data in laravel.
In my Data-table , my value is 1,2,3
my column name is hobby & value is 1,2 . 1 & 2 are related other table, where i stored my hobby name .

### suppose ,

### id || name

1 || gardening
2 || playing

I want to display

### gardening,playing

My controller's Code :-

```
 $interests = DB::table('tbl_interests')  ->join('tbl_interest_masters','tbl_interest_masters.interest','=','tbl_interests.id')
->select()
->get();
return view('profile')
->with('interest',$interests);
```

Don't understand how display data in my view ?
is my code right for read multiple data !!
Note that, i already learn how to read single data with relationship in Laravel.

Comment: i know that , how to use `implode() & explode()` .But don't got a logic !!

Comment: first() gives the first record from the database, get() returns all matching your select. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the select() method from the chain.

```
$interests = DB::table('tbl_interests')
    ->join('tbl_interest_masters','tbl_interest_masters.interest','=','tbl_interests.id')
    ->first();
return view('profile')->with('interest',$interests);
```

Comment: In your profile.blade.php a variable named $interest stores your returned data.

Comment: i know but i want to say , how to read multiple data like array . are you understand

Comment: to read through the array you need to use something like foreach(). for example @foreach($interest as $value){{ $value }}@endforeach

Comment: by the way you can try: {{ var_dump($interest) }}  to see weather it has data

Comment: if you are still using the select() I suggest you remove it as you are not selecting any columns. This might be the reason why you don't see any data. Otherwise, pass the column names you want to select to the select() method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, do you want to return multiple variables?

If so, try this:

```
return view('YOUR_VIEW', compact('VARIABLE1', 'VARIABLE2'));
```

If you are using blade, you can use this to display the returned variables:

```
{{$VARIABLE1}}
```

Loop through an array:

```
@foreach($interests as $interest)
    {{$interest->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: no , my column name is hobby& value is 1,2 . 1 & 2 are related other table, where i stored my hobby name . how can i display it ??

Comment: Right now you are using ->first(), this means it will get the first row of data that matches your request. Try using ->get() or ->all().

Comment: just see my question at now

Comment: I dont know if $interests returns data, if so:

Try displaying the variable in your view using {{$interests->name}}

Comment: its seen error , because i strored data like array . my value is [1,2] . so, this value is not coming in view page, i checked it with `print_r` .

Comment: See Ali's answer, you can loop through an array with:

@foreach($interests as $interest)
{{$interest->name}}
@endforeach

Comment: Are you sure $interests contains data? try using {{dd($interests)}}.